# MOQ - LINQ Predicates in Setup Method

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, moq, predicate

In my method, I have my repository doing this:

```
bool isConditionMet = MyRepository.Any(x => x.Condition == true);
```

I am attempting to mock this using MOQ like so:

```
MyMockedRepository.Setup(x => x.Any(y => y.Condition == true)).Returns(true);
```

However, when the code executes, the repository call always returns false.

Is there a way to do this using MOQ?

** EDIT - Adding code per request **

I am using NHibernate so my Any method is in my base repository and implemented as such:

```
public virtual bool Any(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
{
    return Session.Query<T>().Cacheable().Any(predicate);
}
```

Comment: Could you show more code for `MyRepository` is `Any()` the Linq extension method or part of `MyRepository`?

Comment: I added my Any method per request from my base repository. The mocked class is of `IMyRepository` which is implemented in `MyRepository`.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You need to match invocation arguments using `It.Is`, `It.IsAny` or `It.IsRegex`.

For example, to return `true` for *any* predicate, you could use:

```
MyMockedRepository
     .Setup(x => x.Any(It.IsAny<Expression<Func<T, bool>>>()))
     .Returns(true);
```

Or, you can **match** all expressions, but pass a delegate which will return a value depending on the expression itself:

```
Func<Expression<Func<T, bool>, bool> resultFunc = { ... }
MyMockedRepository
     .Setup(x => x.Any(It.IsAny<Expression<Func<T, bool>>>()))
     .Returns(resultFunc);
```

Comment: Please , can you tell me how resultFunc would look like ?

Comment: @badrslaoui: depends on what/how you're testing. For example, you might know that the method you are testing will check if repository contains any values and simply return true. Or, you might mock a repo using a plain in-memory generic `List<T>`, which means you can simply pass the expression parameter to list's `IQueryable.Any` and let it return `true` or `false`. Or, since the lambda can capture external variables, you can also keep a flag which indicates if you have any data or not, and then return the flag value.