# How to Moq NHibernate extension methods?

Tags: c#, linq, nhibernate, ninject, moq

I'm developing an application using NHibernate for the ORM, NUnit for unit testing and Ninject for my DI. I'm mocking the ISession like so:

```
var session = new Mock<ISession>();
```

With the regular non-mocked session objects I can query them with LINQ extension methods like this:

```
var result = Session.Query<MyEntity>();
```

But when I try to mock this with the following code...

```
session.Setup(s => s.Query<MyEntity>());
```

...I get a runtime "Not supported" exception:

```
Expression references a method that does not belong to the mocked object: s => s.Query<MyEntity>()
```

How can I mock basic queries like this in Moq/NHibernate?

Comment: Just to get idea: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6835366/moq-linq-predicates-in-setup-method

Comment: Just a tip - don't mock ISession. What benefits would those tests give you?
IMHO - write integration tests against your NH queries. For your unit tests, hide your ORM/NH with your own types/interface(s) using DAO/repositories etc instead (and mock/stub/fake these types instead).

Comment: @Roger The benefits it gives you is that you don't have to worry about the state of an actual database. You're **UNIT TESTING**, and that means you should only be testing the code within that method. Your test shouldn't care if someone deleted the database. That's not that method's fault.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Query<T>()` is an extension method, that's why you can't mock it.
Although @Roger answer is the way to go, sometimes it's useful to have specific tests. You can start investigating what `Query<T>()` method does - either by reading the NHibernate code, or using your own tests, and set the appropriate methods on ISession.

**Warning:** creating such a setup will make your test very fragile, and it will break, if the internal implementation of NHibernate changes.

Anyway, you can start your investigation with:

```
var mockSession = new Mock<ISession>(MockBehavior.Strict); //this will make the mock to throw on each invocation which is not setup
var entities = mockSession.Object.Query<MyEntity>();
```

The second line above is going to throw an exception and show you which actual property/method on `ISession` the `Query<T>()` extension method tries to access, so you can set it accordingly. Keep going that way, and eventually you will have a good setup for your session so you can use it in the test.

Note: I'm not familiar with NHibernate, but I have used the above approach when I had to deal with extension methods from other libraries.

Comment: This is the best approach to discover dependencies while you are building your test fitness. +1

Comment: This doesn't answer the question about how to get around the fact that it's an extension method, and therefor unable to be mocked.

Comment: @krillgar, unless I miss something obvious, the very first sentence states just that - you can't mock it using moq (the Q is tagged with moq).

Answer (score 3):

**UPDATE for version 5:**

In the new NHibernate versions `Query<T>` is part of the ISession interface, not an extension function, so it should be easy to mock.

Old answer:

I tried Sunny's suggestion and got this far but got stuck since the `IQuery` is cast to an `NHibernate.Impl.ExpressionQueryImpl` which is internal and I don't think can be extended. Just posting this to save other lost souls a couple hours.

```
var sessionImplMock = new Mock<NHibernate.Engine.ISessionImplementor>(MockBehavior.Strict);
var factoryMock = new Mock<NHibernate.Engine.ISessionFactoryImplementor>(MockBehavior.Strict);
var queryMock = new Mock<IQuery>(MockBehavior.Strict);//ExpressionQueryImpl

sessionImplMock.Setup(x => x.Factory).Returns(factoryMock.Object);
sessionImplMock.Setup(x => x.CreateQuery(It.IsAny<IQueryExpression>())).Returns(queryMock.Object);
sessionMock.Setup(x => x.GetSessionImplementation()).Returns(sessionImplMock.Object);
```