# Mock Linq `Any` predicate with Moq

Tags: c#, linq, unit-testing, mocking, moq

I'm trying to mock `AnyAsync` method in my repository with below codes but repository always returns `false`.

The signature of `AnyAsync` is:

```
Task<bool> AnyAsync<TEntity>(Expression<Func<TEntiry, bool>> predicate)
```

I tried the following setups:

1:

```
mockCustomerRepository.Setup(r => r.AnyAsync(c => c.Email == "some@one.com"))
   .ReturnsAsync(true);
```

2:

```
Expression<Func<CustomerEntity, bool>> predicate = expr => 
    expr.CustomerPerson.Email == "some@one.com";

mockCustomerRepository.Setup(r => r.AnyAsync(It.Is<Expression<Func<CustomerEntity, bool>>>
   (criteria => criteria == predicate))).ReturnsAsync(true);
```

3:

```
mockCustomerRepository.Setup(r => r.AnyAsync(It.IsAny<Expression<Func<CustomerEntity, bool>>>()))
    .ReturnsAsync(true);
```

My test:

```
public class Test 
{
    Mock<ICustomerRepository> mockCustomerRepository;

    public Test()
    {
        mockCustomerRepository = new Mock<ICustomerRepository>();
    }

    [Fact]
    public async Task CustomerTest()
    {   
        var customer = ObjectFactory.CreateCustomer(email: "some@one.com");
        var sut = new CustomerService(mockCustomerRepository.Object);

        var result = await sut.ValidateCustomerAsync(customer);
        .
        .
        .
    }
}
```

My `CustomerService.ValidateCustomerAsync` method:

```
public async Task<OperationResult> ValidateCustomerAsync(CustomerEntity customer)
{
    var errors = new List<ValidationResult>();

    if (await _repository.AnyAsync(c => c.Email == customer.Email))
        errors.Add(new ValidationResult("blah blah")));
```

I've also read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6835366/moq-linq-predicates-in-setup-method) but it doesn't work too.

Comment: Can you show the `repository.AnyAsync` method signature too?

Comment: 'publis async Task<bool> AnyAsync<TEntity>(Expression<Func<TEntiry, bool>> predicate) { return await _context.AnyAsync(predicate); }

Comment: And does this method come from an interface it implements? Sorry for suspecting this, but it should work as it is, so I can ask only if the method comes from an interface you mock?

Comment: Yes it comes from interface.

Comment: Can you include the code where you instantiate the mock too?

Comment: I added mock Instantiating code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following snippet shows the correct way to mock your `AnyAsync` method:

```
[TestMethod]
public async Task TestMethod1()
{
    var fakeCustomerRepo = new Mock<ICustomerRepository>();
    var foo = false;
    fakeCustomerRepo.Setup(repository => repository.AnyAsync(It.IsAny<Expression<Func<CustomerEntity, bool>>>()))
        .Callback<Expression<Func<CustomerEntity, bool>>>(
            expression =>
            {
                var func = expression.Compile();
                foo = func(new CustomerEntity() {Email = "foo@gmail.com"});
            })
        .Returns(() => Task.FromResult(foo));

    var customer = new CustomerEntity() {Email = "foo@gmail.com"};
    var result = await fakeCustomerRepo.Object.AnyAsync<CustomerEntity>(c => c.Email == customer.Email);
    Assert.IsTrue(result);

    customer = new CustomerEntity() { Email = "boo@gmail.com" };
    result = await fakeCustomerRepo.Object.AnyAsync<CustomerEntity>(c => c.Email == customer.Email);
    Assert.IsFalse(result);
}
```

using the above setup you can verify your predicate which is part of your unit behavior.

Comment: Thank you @Old Fox you saved my day.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're running into the difficulties of matching predicates. Funcs or expressions of Funcs use reference-equality, so just using `==` to compare the two instances isn't going to work. (As a general rule, if you can't get `predicate1.Equals(predicate2)` to return true, Moq's argument matchers aren't going to match.)

This is a little unorthodox, but I refer you to [my answer to a similar question for FakeItEasy matchers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21444621/1199), which in turn points you at a number of techniques for validating predicates.

Comment: thank you, I got whats the problem, but I'm not going for implementing another logic expression equality checking. I want  know how to solve this with moq.

Answer (score 0):

All I can see that should cause this problem are two options:

**1.** The repository method does not come from an interface that you should mock to return the desired value, as it is not marked with `virtual`.

**2.** The types (`TEntity`) you use in method do not match when you are using the moq.

```
AnyAsync<TEntity>(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>>
```

as you can setup for let's say `MemberEntity` and call the `ValidateCustomerAsync` with a `CustomerEntity`.

Comment: MemberEntity was copy paste mistake. I fixed the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I am wrong but, but as far as I have read for methods that return only a Task, `.Returns(Task.FromResult(default(object)))` can and should be used.

So in your case it would be `mocksCustomerRepository.Setup(r => r.AnyAsync(c => c.Email == "some@one.com")).Returns(Task.FromResult(true));`

Comment: `ReturnAsync(expectedResult)` method is a wrapper for `.Returns(Task.FromResult(expectedResult))` therefore your answer won't work....